# Image converted from a scikit array to PIL photoimage is being distorted

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I'm trying to add an image that was processed by scikit-image and scipy to a tkinter gui. To add it to the canvas it needs to be either saved as a png, or converted to a `PIL` image. However, when I try to use `ImageTk`'s `Image.fromarray()` it distorts the image a lot. I would prefer not to save it as a png, because it's just an intermediate step for generating data labels.

I tried checking the shapes of the arrays, and they're the same. I tried printing out the images, and the filled_objects is the correct image, while `im` is distorted. So it's not problem in the Tkinter gui. Also, if I don't use `np.asarray()` it produces the same output.

```
def generateCanny(imageName):
    #imagename should be a path to the image, created with os path join
    img = skimage.io.imread(imageName)
    print('orig {}'.format(img.shape))

    gray = np.sqrt((img*img).sum(-1))
    #converts the image to greyscale

    edges = skimage.feature.canny(gray, sigma=3)

    fill = scipy.ndimage.binary_fill_holes(edges)
    return fill

imageName = os.path.join(imagePath, imageStr)
filled_objects = generateCanny(imageName)
a = np.asarray(filled_objects)
im = PIL.Image.fromarray(a)
```

---

Here are the two images, `im` is on the left and `filled_objects` is on the right

[image: scikit to PIL image conversion distortion]

I would think that you could just convert it easily because `filled_objects` is just an array, but `Image.fromarray()` must be doing some processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `fromarray` isn't  interpreting the boolean array `a` correctly. If you convert `a` back to RGB with:

```py
# Extend the array into 3 dimensions, repeating the data:
a = np.repeat(a[...,None],3,axis=2).astype(np.uint8)
# Scale to 0-255:
a = 255*a
im = PIL.Image.fromarray(a)
```

then `im.show()` will display the correct image.

Answer (score 1):

Converting the result to NumPy's `uint8` will do the trick:

```
from skimage import data, color, feature, util
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from scipy.ndimage import binary_fill_holes

rgb = data.hubble_deep_field()
gray = color.rgb2grey(rgb)
edges = feature.canny(gray, sigma=3)
filled_objects = binary_fill_holes(edges)

img_bool = Image.fromarray(filled_objects)
img_uint8 = Image.fromarray(util.img_as_ubyte(filled_objects))

root = tk.Tk()
photo_bool = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_bool)
photo_uint8 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_uint8)
label_bool = tk.Label(root, image=photo_bool).grid(row=1, column=1)
label_uint8 = tk.Label(root, image=photo_uint8).grid(row=1, column=2)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: result]